# Python 3.5.2 - list.sort() not functioning

Tags: list, python-3.x, sorting, numpy, matrix

i'm trying to teach myself some basic coding by recreating 2048, but i've hit a wall.

what i'm trying to do is:

1) create a matrix representing the spaces on the board, occupied by values of zero for empty spaces

2) transpose the axes of the matrix according to the axis the player wants to move the pieces in

3) create a list from each row in the matrix using np.tolist()

4) use listID.sort(key=bool) to sort the list by its truth value, placing the zeroes at one end of the list without rearranging the items that have a value, and saving space by modifying the lists in-place

5) merge adjacent items in the lists that are equal in value

6) use np.columnstack to combine the sorted lists into a matrix, ovewriting the previous matrix

7) transpose the axes to what they originally were

where i'm getting tripped up is at step 4).

the lists don't get sorted at all, nothing changes.

for example a0 (the first row's list) will be [0, 2, 0, 0], but after sorting it, it's STILL [0, 2, 0, 0].

here's my awful, nooby, WIP code to look at and look for yourself if you so desire:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])

print (a)

b = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

c = b
while c == b:
      c = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

d = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

e = d
while e == d:
      e = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

a.itemset((b, c), 2)
a.itemset((d, e), 2)

print (a)

score = np.sum(a)

print (score)

#while 0 in a:
      #direction = input("U, D, L, R?")

      #if direction == "U":
        # mode = 1

      #if direction == "D":
         # mode = 2

      #if direction == "L":
         # mode = 3

      #if direction == "R":
         # mode = 4

#transpose axes according to mode



#sort each array in matrix by boolean value
#refuses to sort?

a0 = a[0].tolist()
a0.sort(key=bool)

a1 = a[1].tolist()
a1.sort(key=bool)

a2 = a[2].tolist()
a2.sort(key=bool)

a3 = a[3].tolist()
a3.sort(key=bool)

#reverse each list depending on mode


#combine back into matrix

print (a0, a1, a2, a3)

a = np.column_stack([[a0], [a1], [a2], [a3]])


print (a)
```

i've searched and searched but nothing i've seen has offered some insight into how i'm doing this wrong, which i'd presume that i am.

edit: SOLVED!

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib
import itertools

a = np.matlib.zeros((4,4))

print (a)

b = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

c = b
while c == b:
      c = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

d = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

e = d
while e == d:
      e = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3)

a.itemset((b, c), float(2))
a.itemset((d, e), float(2))

print (a)

score = np.sum(a)

print (score)

#while 1 in a:
      #direction = input("U, D, L, R?")

      #if direction == "U":
        # mode = 1

      #if direction == "D":
         # mode = 2

      #if direction == "L":
         # mode = 3

      #if direction == "R":
         # mode = 4

#transpose axes according to mode



#sort each array in matrix by boolean value
#refuses to sort?

a0 = a[0].tolist()
a01 = []
a0_2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a0))
for item in a0_2:
      a01.append(float(item))
a01.sort(key=bool)

a1 = a[1].tolist()
a11 = []
a1_2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a1))
for item in a1_2:
      a11.append(float(item))
a11.sort(key=bool)

a2 = a[2].tolist()
a21 = []
a2_2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a2))
for item in a2_2:
      a21.append(float(item))
a21.sort(key=bool)

a3 = a[3].tolist()
a31 = []
a3_2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a3))
for item in a3_2:
      a31.append(float(item))
a31.sort(key=bool)


#reverse each list depending on mode


#combine back into matrix

print (a01, a11, a21, a31)

a = np.vstack([[a01], [a11], [a21], [a31]])


print (a)
```

Comment: Get rid of the stuff that doesn't matter (like all the stuff after the part that fails), and all the redundancy (four copies of the same broken code).

Comment: the print commands are so i can see whether or not the changes i made to the code have allowed it to actually sort the lists. each of the a(number) lines are a  seperate list created from one of the four rows of the matrix.

Comment: I thought the convention for copying the arrays was c[:] = b rather than c = b as that just creates the reference.

Comment: c = b etc aren't array related, that's the code generating coordinates for the game to insert the first two tiles into the matrix. that part is functional. the only part here that isn't working is sorting the lists (a0 to a3)

Comment: Ahh yeah, my bad I was confused for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're trying to "sort by truth values" and that NumPy doesn't have an option for that.  Well, it does, sort of!

```
 a0 = a0[(~a0.astype(bool)).argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

That takes a0 and converts it to True wherever it was nonzero, then inverts that (so False for nonzero), then sorts it (using mergesort for stable sorting).  The use of `argsort()` lets us do "indirect" sorting, i.e. sort one thing by another.

The way you have done it by converting the arrays into lists and then back again is quite inefficient by contrast.  But you won't notice this if the data are small, as they are in your case.